# SKReferenceNode issue in iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sprite-kit

I have found a strange issue starting with iOS 11 where my app will not update sprites on my SKReferenceNode. Basically, I have an "overlay" node (an SKS file that I use for multiple scenes) that has a header and footer. In the header, there is a score bar that expands when the player scores points. I am animating the score bar with an SKAction. Since iOS 11, the score bar does not appear. It happens both on the simulator and device. What's interesting is if I pause/resume the app through the debugger, the score bar immediately appears. I was able to strip down the issue to the following code.

```
import SpriteKit

var overlayNode:SKNode?
var header = SKSpriteNode()
var scoreBar:SKSpriteNode?
var scaleX:CGFloat = 0.3

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

         let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SceneOverlay", ofType: "sks")
         let overlay = SKReferenceNode(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))

        self.addChild(overlay)

        overlayNode = overlay.children.first

        header = overlayNode!.childNode(withName: "header") as! SKSpriteNode

        scoreBar = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redBar")
        scoreBar?.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        scoreBar?.zPosition = 10
        scoreBar?.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        scoreBar?.xScale = 0
        header.addChild(scoreBar!)
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        scaleX += 0.1
        let scoreBarExpand = SKAction.scaleX(to: scaleX, duration: 0.8)

        scoreBar!.run(scoreBarExpand)
        print ("Expanding score bar to \(scaleX)")

    }

}
```

The overlay SKS file is simply this:

[SKS Overlay Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlYm5.png)

If you run this code on an iOS 11 simulator or device, and tap on the screen, the score bar should appear and scale up by 10% each time you tap. However, you won't see anything. You can then pause and resume the app within the Xcode debugger, and the bar will immediately appear and expand. Again, this issue does not appear on an iOS 10 device/simulator.

Any thoughts on what's going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you unpause your scene?  They now start in a pause state for some reason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I've pointed in some other scenarios, but they all point to the same issue. I've discovered a serious issue with iOS11 and SpriteKit. The Game Scene during the transition is getting paused automatically (but only in iOS11).

> Knight0fDragon has also pointed out that it looks like the objects are getting paused on creation not during transition. Same result though.

After transitioning to the scene run

```
myScene.isPaused = false
```

and it should fix the issue, and should have no adverse affects when the game is run on iOS10

Comment: it is paused by default now on creation, not by transition.  I discovered this over the weekend.

Comment: I am thinking that all `SKNodes` get paused on creation, so when you unpause the scene, all nodes will also get unpaused (Another nice 'bug' that they will never fix because that is how they want it by design [without bothering to document this])

Comment: good to know it is on creation, makes slight more sense. But still an undocumented nightmare

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. You are absolutely correct, I checked the state of the header node and it is indeed paused. When I put a breakpoint in, and then resume, it is automatically changing the header's state to not be paused anymore. Very interesting. I had also submitted a bug report on this, so I'm curious to see if Apple comes back with anything. It's too bad this is not documented. I tried to give you a vote but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: glad it helped @MikeL You can mark it as correct in the meantime so that others know that the answer helped, until you get the nesc. reputation

Comment: It looks like this is still an issue as of today. I had posted a bug report back in October with easily reproducible code and it is still open with no response from Apple. Oh well.

Comment: @MikeL yup I just went through this again yesterday, when testing on my ipad (ios10) and switching to my phone (ios11) also worth noting the pausing issue also happens when porting Spritekit over to apple watch os4

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem in my ObjC project.
Knight0fDragons answer didn't work directly for me, but it inspired me.

Strangely first pausing and then unpausing worked for me.

```
    myScene.paused = YES;
    myScene.paused = NO;
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is the solution for me as well (in swift - iOS 14). New to Spritekit, this thing about having breakpoint (using pause/resume) affecting how it works made this a nightmare to debug for me. Still not sure how google got me here (after two days of searching and debugging)
Why is this not a problem for everybody? Are people not using sks files to define their assets for reuse and are setting up assets in code instead? I have a character of sorts with ~10 nodes (arms, legs, head...) so doing like this makes a ton of sense for me.